# how to render latex symbol in tex.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

this piece of latex can be rendered correctly on math.stackexchange.com

```
$\operatorname{var}[\boldsymbol{\mathrm{AD}}+\mathbf{b}] = \boldsymbol{\mathrm{A}} \operatorname{var}[\boldsymbol{\mathrm{D}}]\boldsymbol{\mathrm{A}}^T$
```

gives this figure

[image]

how to render it correctly on tex.stackexchange.com?

Comment: We don't use MathJax: we're interested in TeX, not in approximate representations of its output.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot render tex code directly. tex.stackexchange has not enabled mathjax

If you want to have an image in your post, compile it on your computer and upload a screen shot